# JVM 32 bit installed in the Win7 64 bit Os, but it is not recognized

Tags: java, jvm

I have my toolchain compiled for the JVM-32 bit. And I upgraded my Os to Win7 and now the toolchain is dosen't work anymore Throws the error "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:....bin\libgcc_sjlj_1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform".

I had my Java 64 bit installed and through cmd "java -version" I could see the Java version. Then I uninstalled the JVM- 64 bit and then installed the 32-bit JVM, the cmd says, "Java is unrecognised program", well I have restarted my though. how can this be tackled?

Comment: Fix your `PATH` environment var.

Comment: Your question is probably better asked on another stack site. Just some quick advice is to uninstall it and then reinstall using the "offline" installer. The offline installer is about 40 megs instead of 10 but doesn't need to download as it installs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` leads to your JDM installation directory and that $JAVA_HOME\bin has been added to your `PATH` env variable

This should fix the problem